# AWS lambda function error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, google-drive-api, aws-lambda

I've created a deployment package with python function to create a google drive folder with AWS Lambda. Then I try to test it and I've get an error :

```
    {
  "errorMessage": "main() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      249,
      "handle_event_request",
      "result = request_handler(json_input, context)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I've 2 main files in my .zip. First file are contain main function and another file have security credents , another folders and files are lib's. main file named lambda_function.py with code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse

    flags=argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags=None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE='client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME='Drive API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir=os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir=os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path=os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                 'drive-python-quickstart.json')

    store=Storage(credential_path)
    credentials=store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow=client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent=APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials=tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main(drive_service=None):
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Drive API.

    Creates a Google Drive API service object and outputs the names and IDs
    for up to 10 files.
    """
    credentials=get_credentials()
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service=discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    file_metadata={
        'name': 'Invoices',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
    }
    file=service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                      fields='id').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and my handler in AWS Lambda is lambda_function.main , if I try to test I get an error. If I do it at the console I successfully execute this code and create a folder in google drive api. So maybe whom know what I do wrong ? Help please.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Lambda handler has two arguments event and context for example:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , look , now i fix it but i get the next error ,   "errorMessage": "module initialization error"  and in log it looks like : module initialization error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1078'

Comment: You need to create a deployment package with the libs you are using, read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: i already created it ! all modules are in .zip file. i create it using virualenv , steps are :
1. virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 google
2. install google drive api modules with : pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
3. add to zip file all modules from site-packages

Comment: The error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 
I'm not sure but it could be a problem with the tmp path, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383465/python-read-only-file-system-error-with-s3-and-lambda-when-opening-a-file-for-re