# Errno 30 when deploying pyhanlp to aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, zappa

When I deploy a small python app to aws lambda which depends on pyhanlp to the aws labmda by zappa, I got following error

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read only file system: '/var/task/pyhanlp/static/__init__.py/', line 61, in remove_filenlp_jarLP_DATA_PATH
```

Do I have a way to tell the aws lambda to allow the pyhanlp to install the package not in the tmp?

Edit : I check the post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383465/python-read-only-file-system-error-with-s3-and-lambda-when-opening-a-file-for-re), that can't solve the issue, because pyhanlp(a 3rd party lib) depends on the install path, if I change to tmp, many things will need to be changed too, not realistic

Comment: How do you deploy it?

Comment: check free space in /tmp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Read-only file system Error With S3 and Lambda when opening a file for reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383465/python-read-only-file-system-error-with-s3-and-lambda-when-opening-a-file-for-re)

Comment: @Klaus D. Following this post--https://dev.to/apcelent/deploying-flask-on-aws-lambda-4k42