# how to execute great expectations results into azure functions?

Tags: python, azure-functions, great-expectations

I am trying to deploy Azure functions with Great_expectations folders. The function is getting executed in the local system but facing the below error while executing the function in the portal.

> Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: './tmp' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 405, in _handle__invocation_request invocation_id, fi_context, fi.func, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 612, in _run_sync_func func)(params) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/GETrigger/main.py", line 54, in main os.chmod('./tmp',0o777)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is a missing `tmp` to the file path

```
filepath = '/tmp/' + key
```

for further details you can check the links with related discussions

1. [Azure Function in Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/42218/python-37-file-system-is-read-only.html)
2. [Read Only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383465/error-read-only-file-system-in-aws-lambda-when-downloading-a-file-from-s3)

Comment: Thanks @SaiSakethGuduru-MT. I tried the temp option but I couldn't create the temp folder in wwwroot. Any other option?