# Writing a list to a txt file with Python and AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, txt

I am developing a lambda function that needs to write each element of a list `'my_list'`, in a line of my `'upload.txt'` file.

I have used the next code :

```
my_list=['hello', 'world', 'good', 'morning']
with open("upload.txt", "w+") as a_file:
   for item in my_list:
       a_file.write("%s\n" % item)
   file_dict = {"upload.txt": a_file}
   response = requests.post(url, files=file_dict)
```

When I try to test my lambda it gave me the next error:

```
"errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'upload.txt'",
"errorType": "OSError",
```

It is strange because I will create that file now so why it is written read only file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "Read-only file system" in AWS Lambda when downloading a file from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39383465/error-read-only-file-system-in-aws-lambda-when-downloading-a-file-from-s3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually doesn't allow you to write it; just use `/tmp/` directory to write temporary files for lambda. Just remember the files in `/tmp` are not always cleaned in concurrent run of lambdas.

Comment: means I need to add ´/tmp/´ to ´upload.txt´ path? it is strange because if I used only one element to write in this file it works fine but a list with many elements no

Comment: yes, just instead of upload.txt - use /tmp/upload.txt in both places